# The chat badges does can't be earned on meta

Tags: support, badges

Does anyone know why one can earn the chat badges on Stack Overflow, but can't get it on meta.stackoverflow?

There are 2 chat badges:

- Talkative
- Outspoken

I think that if you get the badge on one of the sites, you should also get it on Meta. Or are there 2 different chats?

When you follow the link to the chat from [MSO/help/badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) it goes to the same place as [SO/help/badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Some badges you just can't earn on per-site Metas. The chat badges are included in that.

Comment: how can you earn the chat badge from on the meta when the link is the same

Comment: You can't. You also can't earn the bounty badges, or the precognitive/beta badges, and apparently constable/sheriff aren't awarded here either.

Comment: no problem I will change the title. thanks for changes the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Meta site has no chat rooms, so it's impossible to get any chat badges.

Comment: Thanks. I think that then the badge should be removed or carry over. with the key word **I think**